# By clicking on upload button, my file is not getting uploaded, even not getting stored in database

Tags: angularjs

When i click on upload button, it is not getting clicked

I tried on local server by using nodejs

```
uc.uploadFiles = function(){

            var userId = $cookies.get("empLoggedIn");

            angular.forEach(uc.files,function(file,i){
                var deferred = $q.defer();

                file.upload = Upload.upload({
                    url:'/upload',
                    data: {file:file,id: userId,description:file.description,keywords: file.keywords,filetype: file.filetype}
                });

                file.upload.then(function(resp){
                    console.log("Success");
                    Notification.success({message:file.name+' uploaded successfully.',positionY: 'bottom',positionX:'left'});
                    return deferred.resolve(resp);
                },function(error){
                    Notification.error({message: 'could not upload '+file.name,positionY: 'bottom',positionX:'left'});
                    return deferred.reject(error);
                });

                promises.push(deferred.promise);
            })

            $q.all(promises).then(function(resp){
                uc.files = [];
                $scope.show = true;
            },function(error){
                console.log(error);
            })
        }
```

The file should get stored in the database and a success message should be displayed

Comment: are you sure that your server is receiving the call with proper data?

Comment: did you check if the file variable in your data object has the right value?

Comment: see the same code my friend has, and it is working fine, even few days back, in my system also, it was working fine. i have checked, no error is reflecting. first my upload button should be active. when i move pointer to the button, it is not showing as a cursor, means i think my upload button is not working

Comment: my upload button itself is not activated, can you plz check my  view code

Comment: <div class="actions pull-right">
              <button type="button" ng-disabled="upload_form.filetype.$error.required||upload_form.tags.$invalid" class="btn btn-sm btn-info" ng-click="uc.uploadFiles()">Upload</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" ng-click="uc.close()">Close </button>
          </div>